# Update single object in Angular Store On Update

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using the '@ngrx/store' to store data locally to display in a table. Part of the functionality of the component is that I have to be able to edit/update the users.

I have set up my user actions, effects, reducer, and selector. I am using an API connection to access this data from a remote database.

My issue is that once I have a list of users in memory, I cannot edit them. Instead, it seems like when I update one of the users, I have to clone the object, then edit it and pass that to my update function.

However, I still cannot seem to update my local in memory copy of the users array state without having to hit the remote server and download them ALL again.

Below is my reducer code:

```
case Actions.UPDATE_SUCCESS: {
      let user= action.payload as User;   
      let position = state.data.findIndex(x => x.id === user.id);
      let temp: User[] = _omit(state.data, position);
      temp.splice(num, 0, test); //This function outright fails to execute
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        usersData: temp
      }
      return newState;
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply update the newly updated user object in existing array of objects by matching its ID.

The `state.data.map....` statement in below code is basically iterating the user array and matching the user id with newly updated user id if that matches it overwrite that existing record with new one.

```
case Actions.UPDATE_SUCCESS: {
   const editedUser = action.payload;
   return {
    ...state,
    usersData: state.data.map((user: User) => (user.id === editedUser.id ? editedUser : user))
   };
  }
```

Comment: Tested functional.

Answer (score 1):

map() method can be used. map() method creates new array.

Idea of Redux and NGRX is to have immutable state. Each state of the application is unchangeable. A new action uses the existing state to calculate a new one. This helps us to avoid accidental state changes via mutable operations. Also allows us to know which action led us to current state.

```
return {
...state,
userData: state.userData.map(uData =>
    udata.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload as User : uData
}
```

Comment: You copied almost exact my above answer :(